# InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type, using Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, type-conversion

I am trying to convert the object to int. I´ve already tried the Convert.ToInt32(object), but it doesn´t work. I don´t understand
what I´m missing. I´m glad, when someone can help.
Heres the code:

```
void Update()
{
        int markNr = 0;
    if (this.m_TuioManager.IsConnected
        && this.m_TuioManager.IsMarkerAlive(this.MarkerID) && isTrue)
    {
        //UserDetected();
        TUIO.TuioObject marker = this.m_TuioManager.GetMarker(this.MarkerID);

        //int object1 = Int32.TryParse(marker, out markNr);
        Debug.Log("The object:" + marker.ToString());

        int object1 = Convert.ToInt32(marker);

        try
        {
            if (markNr == object1)
            {
                Debug.Log("It Worksssss!!!");
                presentationCube.newGame();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed restarting the game");
        }
```

Comment: Well, why do you think `Convert.ToInt32` is able to handle `TUIO.TuioObject`? You sure there isn't a property on that object you want to read instead?

Comment: clearly your marker object is a complex object, and cannot be turned into a number. Perhaps you intended to convert something else?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. What I really want is to compare, what the object is returning(when I show the marker ID in front of the camera), with that, which I have assigned (like int markNr). That´s why I have tried to convert the object into an Integer. The getMarker() method, returns an tuioObject, so I thought, it would be possible to convert it like a object.

Comment: " what the object is returning". firstly, objects don't return anything, methods do. Secondly, again: You cannot convert `marker` to a number because it's a complex object probably with many properties, and there's no way the compiler can possibly interpret it as anything as simple as an integer. What would you expect the result to be in that case? I don't know what the properties of your TuioObject class are, but let's say the object looks like this (in JSON, for simplicity): { "name": "dave", "ID": 3, "occupation": "programmer" }. How would you go about converting that to a number? ...cont'd

Comment: ... You can't, and neither can C#. If you want to convert something to an integer, it has to be something which could be evaluated as an integer or reduced to an integer, for instance a string which contains a number, or a float which will get rounded to the nearest int. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx for things you can convert to an integer. Do you have anything like that? Maybe something which is a property _within_ `marker`?. Or maybe even that property is already an integer and you can just directly compare e.g. `if markNr == marker.ID`??

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your answer. Yes, sorry I meant of course method is returning. It works, with an other method(from library), that returns an integer :)

Answer (score 2):

Only objects that represent an integer can be converted to an integer. TuioObject is not a representation of an integer, but it may **contain** one or more integers or values which can be converted to an integer.

What I suggest you do, is to add a function to TuioObject, which returns the integer you need. For example if the number you want to compare is an id:

```
public int GetId ()
{
    return id;
}
```

Then replace

```
int object1 = Convert.ToInt32(marker);
```

with

```
int id = marker.GetId();
```

If TuioObject is in an external framework, which you cannot edit, you can create a subclass of TuioObject with the new function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But with GetId() I wanted to return an array with numbers from 0 to 4 later. And then I wanted to compare numbers with the numbers in the array. So I´m not only want to return one id.